# How to pass maven goals through jenkins url?

Tags: maven, jenkins

I would like to pass maven goals thorough url as parameters. How can i configure maven goals to read values from url?

In the attached screen shot, I would like to pass -DJiraLabel value through url parameter? How can i achieve this.

[image]

Comment: The configuration in Jenkins of your root pom is wrong. This is by default `pom.xml` nothing more...

Comment: i dont have problem with pom.xml. My query is how would i pass goals dynamically

Comment: Why do you need different goals? apart from that an `mvn clean install` usually does not make sense. You should use `mvn clean deploy` if you have a repository manager otherwise a `mvn clean package` is enough.